# xlwings python continuously return updating data in UDF

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a class updating a live value:

```
class LiveUpdate():

    def __init__(self):

        self.x=0

        self.t1 = threading.Thread(target=self._refresh_value)
        self.t1.start()

    def _refresh_value(self):

        while True:
            self.x=self.x+1


updater=LiveUpdate()

@xw.func
def return_live_x():
    return updater.x
```

When I call return_live_x as an UDF , how do i get it to continuously return 1,2,3,4 etc in excel?

Comment: It's likely you will get `1000, 3000, 5000` on call of `return_live_x`. Read about [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), consider the Example on this site.

Comment: I dont mind getting 1,2,5,7,8 etc its more about getting the UDF to auto refresh the value in excel when self.x updates and return_live_x() is being used in excel

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... its more about getting the UDF to auto refresh the value in excel

UDF's are called if Excel decides to recalculate or Key pressed to do so manually.

Don't know if it's possible to Start and Run a Python Script Forever in the Background using `xlwings`.

I could Imagin the follwoing, **untested Code**:

> **Note**: This Code could lead Excel to stall.

```
class LiveUpdate():
    def __init__(self, wb):
        self.wb = wb
        ...

    def _refresh_value(self):
        while True:
            self.x += 1
            self.wb.sheets[0].range('A1').value = self.x
            time.sleep(1)

@xw.func
def start_LiveUpdate():
    LiveUpdate(xw.Book.caller())
    return 'started'
```

Comment: you can get python to start and continuously update if you use optimzed_connection=True in the vba module.

Comment: im more interested to see if i can get start_LiveUpdate to return the most up to date value of self.x